# Plotly not working on julia 1.8 on Macbook M1

Tags: plotly, julia

I am running Julia v1.8 on a Macbook Pro M1.
There are no errors displayed but the plot window never shows:

```
   using PlotlyJS

   plot(rand(10))
```

From what I've read online this should be working now.

Comment: I feel like there are so many seg fault issues with plotting in Julia and the M1...

Comment: You must be using one of the rc versions since Julia 1.8 has not been released yet. Try reporting this issue to the PlotlyJS project instead.